# LaTeX: Copy and Paste Symbols

Tags: math-mode, symbols, tex-core, mathematics

Community,

I want to solve these 2 following things:

1. Copy and paste the LaTeX-symbols, so mathematical symbols, from a pdf-document 1 to 1 into a writing document.
2. Copy and paste the LaTeX-symbols, so mathematical symbols, from a website 1 to 1 into a writing document.

I tried to copy from an example mathematical script document from the internet. I marked and then copied a little part of the script, just one line of it. After that I pasted it into Microsoft Word, Microsoft Word didn't recognise it all exactly the same from the script. So the problem with Word is, that it doesn't support the whole LaTeX environment.
The same problem I have with the 2. thing.

How can I do it still eventually with Microsoft Word or which programs are working as text editor instead of Microsoft Word for my 2 things? How can I do it maybe with VSCode?

How can I copy and paste the LaTeX-symbols from a website and pdf-document into a writing document?

Comment: if you use `unicode-math` most characters will copy from the pdf, but in general you can not expect text copied from the pdf to be usable. A LaTeX document is a computer program that produces typeset output, you can not, in general, re-create a usable input form from the output. You can't make an egg out of an omlette.

Comment: if you believe you may simply copy and paste a pdf picture into a wordprocessor as source code, you are deluded; otoh, there are specific pdf2docx converters out there which might do the job, but ymmv.